# Is it okay for SEO if the content in <h1> stays always the same and <h2> changes depending on article?

Tags: html, seo, semantics

I'm building a website that contains news. I've got a page with a list of the news articles. And a second page which shows the details of the articles.

And I've got some questions about the structure of the page which shows a single article.

Here is how the page looks like:

```
<body>
    <header data-role="header">
        <h1>Article detail</h1>
    </header>

    <div data-role="content">

        <article>
            <header>
                <h2>Article title</h2>
                <p class="lead">Lead</p>
                <p><time datetime="2012-10-15" pubdate="pubdate">October 15, 2012</time></p>
            </header>
            <p>Article content</p>
        </article>

    </div>
</body>
```

In a SEO point of view, is ok if the `<h1>` is always the same and only the `<h2>` change depending of the article?

I was thinking to put the article title in the `<h1>` too. But it means we will have the same `<h1>` and `<h2>`. I don't really know if it's a good practice.

What's your advice?

Comment: I don't think it's relevant for this question that you use JQuery Mobile, is it?

Comment: nope, the question is the same with or without using jQuery Mobile

Comment: Okay, I removed the JQuery reference and changed the title of the question (is it okay that way? If not, edit it :)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think having "Article detail" as heading doesn't make sense here. It would be similar if the top heading of this very question on Stack Overflow would be "Question". Or if a blog post would have the heading "Blog post".

Your example (let's assume the article title is "John Doe wins!") would produce this [outline](http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/):

```
- Article detail
-- John Doe wins!
```

The page does not contain an "Article detail", it *is* the article itself, right?

As your pages are part of a website, the heading for the whole page should probably be the *site heading* (the same for all pages that belong to this site).

The article title would be the main content of that page, but it's still a "child" of the site, so it gets hierarchy level 2.

If you'd have a site navigation ("All news", "Contact", …), this would get level 2 also.

So (let's assume the site is called "ACME News") this would be a suitable outline for the page:

```
- ACME News
-- John Doe wins!
-- (Navigation)
```

As long as you use sectioning elements (`section`, `article`, `nav`, `aside`), you may use `h1` everywhere. Or, as you did it in your example, use the headings `h2`-`h6` according to the ("calculated") outline. Semantically there would be no difference.

If and how search engines handle this … well, some probably understand HTML5, some don't. Some talk about it, some not. The (good) search engines will be able to interpret the structure of HTML5 documents (resp. don't "de-rank" pages just because they use HTML5 according to the spec). It's the way how pages will be marked up, some even now and *many* more in the future.

For your site, I bet most search engines wouldn't even bother which way you choose. It's a relatively minor detail for this extent (only 2-3 headings per page).

Comment: You're right. I think I will follow this recommendation : 

_When the main content of the page (i.e. excluding footers, headers, navigation blocks, and sidebars) is all one single self-contained composition, that content may be marked with an article, but it is technically redundant in that case (since it's self-evident that the page is a single composition, as it is a single document)._ - [HTML 5.1 Nightly](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-article-element).

I won't use the `<article>`tag because the page is an article itself.

Answer (score 0):

Normally in SEO h1 tag is used to signify Article heading.

In blog h1 is used to highlight starting point of an article which is naturally heading of the page.

Now if you wish to keep your heading constant it wont make much difference.

What will happen if you do this is

You will be having a lot of articles under the same Heading which in turn might provide you a single backlink as it might rank your page as per the most visited article.

So with respect to aesthetic view and also for better indexing we should use different H1 tags for different articles.

Comment: Not only an Article heading, but in general a page title.

Answer (score 0):

I think putting article title in h2 tag will improve your SEO score. H1 tag is more important but you have to also define other SEO tags like h1 to h6, bold, italic, em tag, acronym tag, dfn tag, abbr tag and strong tag in article content for better SEO result.

Now, you can also define article tag in your content to represent your article content. It separates your article content independently from the other content on your site.